# Excel: Create a dropdown menu from a dynamic list without duplicates

Tags: excel, list, duplicates

The question pretty much says it I guess. For detailed information:

I have a range of cells (F3:F2000) in which there can be names filled in. I want to be able to count the amount of times, a name has been mentioned. I am doing this with =COUNTIF(...), which is not the problem and works perfectly fine. But I want to be able to have a cell with a dropdown menu in which you can choose from all names mentioned in F3:F2000. My approach so far is to create a dynamic list, and then use this for the dropdown menu. But obviously it just uses all the entries and therefore I get a bunch of the same names. So how do I remove the duplicates? I assume this has to be done in the dynamic list.

Here is my formula for the dynamic list:

```
=OFFSET(Logbook!$F$3:$F$2000,0,0,COUNTA(Logbook!$F$3:$F$2000)+1,1)
```

And for those stuck with german excel like me :(, the german version:

```
=BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Logbook!$F$3:$F$2000;0;0;ANZAHL2(Logbook!$F$3:$F$2000)+1;1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this posting, I think it answers your question.
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/25/create-a-drop-down-list-containing-only-unique-distinct-alphabetically-sorted-text-values-using-excel-array-formula